# Why js function does not change the html code permanently?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, onload

In the `body` of the HTML page is a button that calls the Javascript function from an `onclick` event, and in the `head` is the Javascript function that I would like to run with more permanent results.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       function loadformTest(){
         document.getElementById('departement').value = '31';
         document.getElementById('ville').value = 'toulouse';
         document.getElementById('quoi').value = 'société de services informatiques';
         annuaire = document.getElementById('annuaire');
         recherche = document.getElementById('recherche');
         annuaire.innerHTML = 'Annuaire'
         annuaire.href = "http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/pagesblanches";
         recherche.innerHTML = 'Annuaire'
         recherche.href = "https://google.fr";
      }

      </script>

    </head>
    <body>
     <form id="form" action="" method="post">
         <p>Quoi,Qui : <input id="quoi" name="quiQuoiSaisi" type="text"/></p>
         <p>Ville : <input id="ville" name="ville" type="text"/></p>
         <p>N°Département : <input id="departement" name="departement" type="text"/><p>
         <button onclick="loadformTest()">Valeurs par défaut </button>
     </form>
     <a id="recherche" href="" target="_blank"></a>
     <a id="annuaire" href="" target="_blank"></a>
   </body>
</html>
```

But if same function is called in the body tag on load the page, the changes are permanent.

My question is perhaps due to my lack of knowledge of Javascript !

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "more permanent"?

Comment: Do you want those values to appear by default?

Comment: When I click the button, the function runs but the HTML changes are not permanent: the next second everything returns to its original state in the firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the buttons onclick to include "return false;". At the moment the button is causing the page to reload after running your script.

```
<button onclick="loadformTest(); return false;">Valeurs par défaut </button>
```

or if you specify the type of your button to be a button (as opposed to submit, which might be the browsers default) then the button won't cause a refresh.

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadformTest()">Valeurs par défaut </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadformTest()">Valeurs par défaut </button>
```

so the button does not perform a form submit to an empty url (action tag should not be empty).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because when the button is clicked, the form is submitted and since action is set to `""` the whole page will just reload itself. Try to add an `onsubmit` to your form like this:

```html
<form id="form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: I did not know it was possible to write imput tags without the form tag. Thank you I checked it's quite accurate !